# Compare 2 React Components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am writing a Webpack loader that creates React components. Now I want to test my generated components to see if they have been created properly. Therefore, I want to compare my component withe a reference component created the normal way with react. But how can I do this with jest?

```
test('component is created properly', () => {
  const ComponentA = createReactComponentWithMyLoader();
  class ComponentB extends extends React.Component {/* ... */}
  expect(ComponentA).toEqual(ComponentB);
})
```

This does fail

> FAIL  test/serializer/react.test.ts ● ReactSerializer › an element
>
> expect(received).toEqual(expected)
>
> Expected value to equal: [Function Foo]     Received: [Function Foo]
>   Difference: Compared values have no visual difference.

Comment: Why not match the html strings for equality?

Comment: Because I would only match part of the truth, other parts could be broken

Comment: You need to clarify in your question what **exactly** you actually want to compare/match between `ComponentA` and `ComponentB`. "created properly" doesn't indicate whether you mean rendered/mounted HTML comparison or comparison of lifecycle events or function outputs.